# How to get the full information of runtime error instead of <Timeout exceeded getting exception details>?

Tags: android, debugging, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

So I'm trying out xamarin in VS2017, but found this undhandled error:

```
Unhandled Exception:

Java.Lang.SecurityException: <Timeout exceeded getting exception details>
```

This is very clueless. How can I get the full information of the runtime error like in Android Studio?

Comment: You surround the exception with try-catch block So You can log the exception message

Comment: @FarabiAbdelwahed yes it works. But it's a work around which is counter productive, not a real solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting assistance from Microsoft, I finally found the solution.

**TL;DR**

Use VS Android device log and filter with "mono-rt" or "Error"

**Complete Answer:**

There are 2 solution:

**1. Using Android Studio logcat:**

Open the Android Studio logcat (View > Tool Windows > Logcat). From the logcat window, choose the device, choose the Xamarin.Android deployed application, and choose logcat for Error

[image: Make sure you choose the right device and then the Xamarin.Android application you've deployed and choose logcat for error]

Android logcat will display the runtime error:

[image: error from android studio logcat]

**2. Using Visual Studio Android Device Log:**

Open the Visual Studio Android Device Log(Tools > Android > Device Log).

Here is the tricky bit: Unlike Android Studio, VS list all of the device log, not limited to the Xamarin.Android app deployed. So somehow we have to use the filter to get the relevant information. The problem is, what filter should we use? I used my application name and the error didn't show up. It turns out that when the error happen, the log doesn't contain any of the application name. Instead it has "mono-rt" tag with "Error" type.

So there you have it. Filter it with "mono-rt" tag or "Error" type and you will find the error information

[image: Log with mono-rt tag]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while calling some native API,
solved it by

Put a try catch around the block of got which is throwing the error.
Put a breakpoint in the catch block, you can get actual details of the exception.

Comment: Well this works. But it's still a work around and counter productive (debug > put try catch > test > delete try catch). Is there really no solution that can operate like android studio? is this the limit of xamarin?

Comment: Update: also i found where there's an instance where the error happens inside the try block.

Comment: I am not aware of any alternative solution to this.